# meteor integrate with jsplumb

Tags: meteor, jsplumb

I am doing a project and want to integrate with jsplumb meteor , and install jsplumb with meteor, but not to call it I've read some of the documentation jsplumb but nothing related to meteor , I just need like using nothing more

Answer (score 0):

jsPlumb is available as a [Meteor package](https://atmospherejs.com/jsplumb/jsplumb) so it should be easy to use them together. You'll still have to learn Meteor. You can start with [Discover Meteor](https://www.discovermeteor.com/) or with the [tutorial](https://www.meteor.com/tutorials/blaze/creating-an-app).